# Create file with Unit Test with Android in the emulator or android device folder

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I am new to Unit Testing.

I was trying to create a folder using a Unit Test

```
@Test
public void testGenerateFile() throws IOException {
    Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();

    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(),"myfile");
    file.createNewFile();
    byte[] data1={1,1,0,0};
    //write the bytes in file
    if(file.exists())
    {
        OutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fo.write(data1);
        fo.close();
        System.out.println("file created: "+file);
    }
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

I also try to get the context from

```
Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
```

But the file that was generated is in the folder

```
file created: /var/folders/yh/mkknvc7n2qx2k4swl_mtj7lw0000gn/T/robolectric-Method_testGenerateFile9017115247567873084/org.robolectric.default-dataDir/files/myfile
```

This is a folder generated for robolectric instrumented test. How can I get the folder to the real emulator or android device?

Comment: Don't use Robolectric for that. It is specifically designed to avoid having to use an actual device or emulator, but that's what you want. Test your file creation using an instrumented test executed on an actual Android device/emulator.

Comment: How can I use an instrumented test on an android device/emulator?

Comment: It might make sense for you to first take a look at the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @michpohl

```
import android.content.Context;

import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withSubstring;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertTrue;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<ActionBarDrawerActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        ActionBarDrawerActivity.class, false, true);

@Test
public void navigateHelloWorld() throws Exception {
    onView(withId(R.id.tv_gta_info)).check(matches(withText(containsString("Defesa"))));
    onView(withId(R.id.tv_gta_info)).check(matches(withSubstring("Defesa")));

    onView(withId(R.id.btn_servicos_animal)).perform(click());

    assertTrue(true);
}

@Test
public void checkFileCreation() throws Exception {
    Context context = mActivityRule.getActivity().getApplication().getBaseContext();

    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "myfile.txt");
    file.createNewFile();
    byte[] data1={1,1,0,0};
    //write the bytes in file
    if(file.exists())
    {
        OutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fo.write(data1);
        fo.close();
        System.out.println("file created: "+file);
    }
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

This is my code that I use to create a file in the android emulator.

Don't forget to add these import on "build.gradle" file.

```
defaultConfig {
    
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/AL2.0'
    exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
}
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    animationsDisabled = true
}


dependencies {

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1' // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
testImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.3.0'
testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.4' // Robolectric environment
testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.3.0' // Optional -- truth
testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.3.3' // Optional -- Mockito framework
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3' // Optional -- Hamcrest library
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0' // Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0' // Optional -- UI testing with UI Automator

}
```